# Nested AngularJS Modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my website, when you click a button, it opens up a modal. Here's the basic controller code for it:

```
var modalOptions = {
     animation: true,
     templateUrl: 'somehtml.html',
     controller: 'MyController',
     backdrop: 'static',
     scope: $scope
  };
modalInstance = $modal.open(modalOptions);
```

When you're in this modal, you can input in some information and then hit submit. How do I create a modal on top of the existing modal that says something like "Currently adding to the database..." and it closes when it's finished.

I've looked around and there's very little on how to do nested modals.

Comment: twitter-bootstrap modals do not support being nested. You will have to roll your own solution in order to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, there is no way to 'nest' modals in this fashion. For what you're trying to accomplish, an ngShow/ngHide change displaying the "Currently adding to the database..." when the submit button is clicked would be your best option, effectively re-using the modal instance / template.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing for the most part. Thank you!